# Recording current development of research mathematics

Tags: mathematics, mathematics-social-history

Are there historians of science that are systematically recording current activity in research mathematics ?

For example, a decade ago there was a lot of stuff through blogs and Mathoverflow, nowadays there at least sociological interactions on Twitter. All this will probably be easy to browse in the future thanks to the Wayback Machine.

> but what about private emails of researchers with colleagues and with journals, are there efforts to archive this very valuable material?

Comment: I suspect amount of stuff in blog and other non-published venues is too great for people to browse through sufficiently to find all things of interest and to establish nontrivial historical trends. However, I also suspect this can be done using various archives by trans-human intelligences (AI, enhanced humans, etc.) that undoubtedly will begin replacing us in 100 to 150 years. The real question is whether these entities consider it worth while, or the issues so trivial from their view that it would be like us seeking to know how many characters appear in each book published in the 1800s.

Comment: When you say "private emails", perhaps it should be clarified that what's meant here is still work-related communication, typically using university/employer email resources (not purely private/personal information outside any work context), for which there's not the same expectation of privacy as for purely private emails, and which are (unlike private emails) in principle accessible to history researchers (with various data protection requirements). In the answers it seems there's been some misunderstanding on that point.

Answer (score 2):

> but what about private emails of researchers with colleagues and with journals, are there efforts to archive this very valuable material?

Private emails are supposed to be private and any efforts to archive them would be illegal.

Comment: Obviously I meant a legally sound procedure whereby all members of an email exchange agree for it to be made publicly available.

Comment: I agree with this answer. If I want to make some of my private e-mails public, then I post them. Otherwise they are private. It is the author who decides what of his/her correspondence should be made public.

Comment: @user14874: Please point out where in your question a legally sound  procedure is described.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "private". If your email account is provided by an employer, your emails are not private but work documents like anything else you produce, and there can still be legal requirements to archive them and (if the employer is a public body) release them to freedom of information requests, with personal information redacted. Therefore it's wise not to use your work email for personal things but get a separate personal address.

Comment: @StephanMatthiesen: Private email accounts are **not** provided by the employer exactly for that reason: otherwise these are not private.

Comment: Indeed, but that's not the point here. The original question was about scientists discussing their work, for which they typically use their university accounts, not a private account from a separate provider. So I just suggest your answer could be improved in that respect. I assume we agree that employers usually have a policy along the lines of "Employees should not have an expectation of privacy regarding any information transmitted on [employer's] systems or stored on [employer's] systems" (example quoted from a random US university, ).

Comment: Of course non-public emails like most other work-documents aren't archived publicly and there are a lot of data protection rules to consider, but that doesn't mean that they are never accessible to HSM researchers for analysis. That was the original question; the answer is more complex than "would be illegal".